Files are not updated after the Jenkins Build success triggered by the GitHub Actions
I am trying to fetch the last and latest build numbers or build job ids and save them into the text files like old_build_number.txt contains the last successful build number or id and new_build_number.txt contains the all build Ids as build_number - status example as given below from the Jenkins after the Build Job successful by using the trigger-jenkins-build.yml triggered through the GitHub Actions.
And the GitHub URL GitHub Project URL , YAML file trigger-jenkins-build.yml and GitHub Action Results.
trigger-jenkins-build.yml :
-name: Trigger Jenkins Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  trigger-jenkins:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Get Commit Message
        id: get-commit-message
        run: |
          COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%s)
          echo "Commit Message: ${COMMIT_MESSAGE}"
          echo "COMMIT_MESSAGE=${COMMIT_MESSAGE}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Read JSON Configuration
        id: read-json
        run: |
          if [ -f config.json ]; then
            JOB_NAME=$(jq -r '.buildConfig.jobName' config.json)
            if [ "$JOB_NAME" == "null" ] || [ -z "$JOB_NAME" ]; then
              echo "Error: 'jobName' not found in config.json"
              exit 1
            fi
            echo "JOB_NAME=${JOB_NAME}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "Error: config.json file not found"
            exit 1
          fi

      - name: Extract Job Name
        id: extract-job-name
        run: |
          EXTRACTED_JOB_NAME=$(echo "${{ env.COMMIT_MESSAGE }}" | grep -oP '(?<=Activity: )\S+' || echo "")
          if [ -z "$EXTRACTED_JOB_NAME" ]; then
            EXTRACTED_JOB_NAME=${{ env.JOB_NAME }}
          fi
          echo "JOB_NAME=${EXTRACTED_JOB_NAME}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Fetch Local Build Number
        id: fetch-local-build-number
        run: |
          BUILD_NUMBER_FILE=".github/build_numbers/old_build_number.txt"
          echo "Checking for build number file at: $BUILD_NUMBER_FILE"
          if [ -f "$BUILD_NUMBER_FILE" ]; then
            LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER=$(cat "$BUILD_NUMBER_FILE")
            echo "Found local build number: $LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER"
          else
            echo "No build number file found. Initializing build number to 0."
            LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER=0
          fi
          if [ -z "$LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER" ] || ! [[ "$LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER=0
          fi
          echo "LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER=${LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Fetch Latest Jenkins Build Number
        id: fetch-jenkins-build-number
        run: |
          LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER=$(curl -s -u "${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER }}:${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}" \
              "${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL }}/job/${{ env.JOB_NAME }}/lastBuild/api/json?tree=number" | jq -r '.number')
          echo "Jenkins returned latest build number: $LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER"
          if [ "$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER" == "null" ] || [ -z "$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER" ] || ! [[ "$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            echo "Error: Unable to retrieve Jenkins build number. Exiting."
            exit 1
          fi
          echo "LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER=${LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Determine New Build Number
        id: determine-build-number
        run: |
          if [ "${{ env.LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER }}" -ge "${{ env.LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER }}" ]; then
            BUILD_NUMBER=$((LOCAL_BUILD_NUMBER + 1))
          else
            BUILD_NUMBER=$((LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER + 1))
          fi
          BUILD_NUMBER=$(printf "%02d" "$BUILD_NUMBER")
          echo "Determined new build number: $BUILD_NUMBER"
          echo "BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Trigger Jenkins Build
        id: trigger-build
        shell: bash
        env:
          JENKINS_URL: ${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL }}
          JENKINS_USER: ${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER }}
          JENKINS_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}
          JOB_NAME: ${{ env.JOB_NAME }}
          BUILD_NUMBER: ${{ env.BUILD_NUMBER }}
          DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT: development
        run: |
          TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL=$(echo "$JENKINS_URL" | sed 's:/*$::')
          CRUMB=$(curl -s -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_API_TOKEN" "$TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/json" | jq -r '.crumb')
          if [ -z "$CRUMB" ]; then
            echo "Failed to obtain crumb. Exiting."
            exit 1
          fi
          FULL_URL="${TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/build"
          echo "Triggering Jenkins build with build number: $BUILD_NUMBER at URL: $FULL_URL"
          response=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "$FULL_URL" \
               --user "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_API_TOKEN" \
               --header "Jenkins-Crumb:$CRUMB" \
               --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
               --data-urlencode "BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER" \
               --data-urlencode "DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT=$DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT")
          if [ "$response" -ne 201 ]; then
            echo "Error: Jenkins build trigger failed with response code $response. Exiting."
            exit 1
          fi
          echo "Jenkins build triggered successfully."

      - name: Re-fetch Latest Jenkins Build Number & Status
        id: refetch-jenkins-build-number-status
        run: |
          sleep 10  # Wait for Jenkins to update the build number and status
          LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER=$(curl -s -u "${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER }}:${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}" \
              "${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL }}/job/${{ env.JOB_NAME }}/lastBuild/api/json?tree=number" | jq -r '.number')
          echo "Refetched latest Jenkins build number: $LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER"
          if [ "$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER" == "null" ] || [ -z "$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER" ] || ! [[ "$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            echo "Error: Unable to retrieve Jenkins build number after triggering. Exiting."
            exit 1
          fi
          BUILD_STATUS=$(curl -s -u "${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER }}:${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}" \
              "${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL }}/job/${{ env.JOB_NAME }}/$LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?tree=result" | jq -r '.result')
          if [ "$BUILD_STATUS" == "null" ] || [ -z "$BUILD_STATUS" ]; then
            BUILD_STATUS="in progress"
          elif [ "$BUILD_STATUS" == "SUCCESS" ]; then
            BUILD_STATUS="success"
          else
            BUILD_STATUS="failed"
          fi
          echo "Refetched build status: $BUILD_STATUS"
          echo "LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER=${LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "BUILD_STATUS=${BUILD_STATUS}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Update Old and New Build Numbers
        id: update-build-numbers
        run: |
          OLD_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE=".github/build_numbers/old_build_number.txt"
          NEW_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE=".github/build_numbers/new_build_number.txt"
          mkdir -p .github/build_numbers
          echo "Updating old build number file at: $OLD_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE"
          echo "${{ env.LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER }}" > "$OLD_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE"
          echo "Updating new build number file at: $NEW_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE"
          echo "${{ env.LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER }} - ${{ env.BUILD_STATUS }}" >> "$NEW_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE"

          # Configure Git and commit the updated build numbers
          git config user.name "github-actions"
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git fetch origin || { echo "git fetch failed"; exit 1; }
          git reset --hard origin/${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} || { echo "git reset failed"; exit 1; }
          git add "$OLD_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE" "$NEW_BUILD_NUMBER_FILE"
          if ! git diff --cached --quiet; then
            git commit -m "Update build numbers to ${{ env.LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER }} and status ${{ env.BUILD_STATUS }}" || { echo "git commit failed"; exit 1; }
            git push origin HEAD:${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} || { echo "git push failed"; exit 1; }
          else
            echo "No changes to commit."
          fi

      - name: Post-job Cleanup
        if: always()  # Always run this step even if previous steps fail
        run: |
          echo "Starting post-job cleanup..."
          if [ -x "/usr/bin/make" ]; then
            echo "Make executable found at /usr/bin/make"
          else
            echo "Error: Make executable not found at /usr/bin/make. Exiting."
            exit 1
          fi
          echo "Post-job cleanup completed successfully."

And the old_build_number.txt, new_build_number.txt files are created under the folder .github/build_numbers as given the links above.
I am not sure what went wrong to update the text files after the successful Jenkins build job.

I have corrected the above mentioned yaml file trigger-jenkins-build.yml to save the build numbers in the JSON file as build_number.json whenever the Jenkins build job successfully triggered.
This way I solved the issue about saving the old and new build numbers in a single file rather than two separate files, more over it is easy to reading and updating the contents from the same file.
Thanks.

Resetting the repo after you save the files wipes out your changes
      git reset --hard origin/${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} || { echo "git reset failed"; exit 1; }


The above statement is the cause of the problem?

That's why I quoted it :)

Yes its solved my issue, but its continuously trigger the Jenkins build since its pushing the changes to repository that triggers new build. How to solve this ? I tried to add that into artifacts but no luck.

If this answers your original question feel free to accept the answer and open a new question to continue troubleshooting.
